# How to compare Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

How can I compare `Calendar` in Java? I want check if `now_2`is newer then `now_1` like this:

```
    Calendar now_1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    sleep(10000); //sleep for 10 second
    Calendar now_2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    if(now_2.isNewer(now_1)){
        //BIG FAIL
    }
```

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970296/comparing-two-calendar-objects

Comment: Where did you find `isNewer` method in `Calendar`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.compareTo(c2);
```

**Return:**

- Value less than 0:  c1 is before the c2
- Value greater than 0: c1 is after the c2.

Please check and vote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12970352/4933902).