# Determining the latest of two dates, using Calender

Tags: android

I have two instances of Calender, expiryDate and nowDate. The date of expiryDate is set to 16 august 2020, nowDate gets the current date.

```
Calendar expiryDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar nowDate = Calendar.getInstance();

expiryDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
expiryDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
expiryDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
```

What code can determine which instance has the latest date?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12970352/6478047

Comment: One thing to keep in mind for your code is the same-day check  - e.g. is "6PM vs midnight (start of day)" considered expired?

Answer (score 1):

First Convert your Calendar to date Object.

```
Date date1 = calendar.getTime();
```

then use date compareTo method.

Date class has its own methods for date comparison: compareTo

```
if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
    Log.i("app", "Date1 is after Date2");
    }
```

Comment: this would be an unnecessary conversion... also if you do convert Calendar to Date, just use the before and after methods of the Date class thats easier

Comment: @Kushan if want to write code one then it is ok , i think no problem

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is use milliseconds Kotlin:

```
  if (expiryDate.timeInMillis< nowDate.timeInMillis) {
         // Expired
   } else {
         // Not expired
   }
```

Java

```
  if (expiryDate.getTimeInMillis() < nowDate.getTimeInMillis()) {
         // Expired
   } else {
         // Not expired
   }
```

Comment: time is a protected variable in Calendar class

Comment: @Kushan we can access using `time` in kotlin

Comment: yea, @ManoharReddy he had not mentioned it was in kotlin before the edit :)

Comment: Yes, copied Kotlin code so thats why mistake was made :)

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest, get epoch millis from both and compare the long millis

```
Calendar expiryDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar nowDate = Calendar.getInstance();

expiryDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
expiryDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
expiryDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);

long nowMillis = nowDate.getTimeInMillis();

long expiryDateMillis = expiryDate.getTimeInMillis();

if(nowMillis>expiryDateMillis){
  //now date is after expiry
}else{
  //now date is before expiry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the `Calendar.compareTo()` function is equivalent to the `getTimeInMillis` solutions - so why not just use the Calendar's code:

So OP would be:

```
if (nowDate.compareTo(expiryDate) > 0) {
    // expired
} else {
    // not expired
}
```

Note - this does not solve the "same-day" case.

For reference here's the Calendar's [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-3.2.4_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Calendar.java#1399) of the `compareTo`:

```
public int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar) {
    if (anotherCalendar == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    long timeInMillis = getTimeInMillis();
    long anotherTimeInMillis = anotherCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if (timeInMillis > anotherTimeInMillis) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (timeInMillis == anotherTimeInMillis) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed this is the same as @Manohar Reddy 's duplicate reference in comments so post most likely will be tagged as such.