# Java same Dates containing different time in milli seconds

Tags: java

I have two calendar objects, they seems to contain same dates but the compareTo() method is returning -1 as result, Can any one explain the reason behind this.

On debugging the two Calendar objects, the result is shown as :

2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z

for both calendar objects but the compareTo() is returning -1. Even the long time in millis for both dates are different.

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: Probably a timezone issue, but what *are* the millis for those two dates?

Comment: Date 1 millis : 1401561000000
Date 2 millis : 1401595200000

Comment: See my answer for how to ignore the milliseconds

Comment: @Hitesh Edit your Question with pertinent facts rather than appending as comments.

Comment: If the long time in milliseconds is different then they must be different times, what is your `DateFormat`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, have a look at the `Calendar` code (this is from JDK 1.7.0-13):

```
public int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar) {
    return compareTo(getMillisOf(anotherCalendar));
}

private int compareTo(long t) {
    long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
    return (thisTime > t) ? 1 : (thisTime == t) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

It should be obvious that if the two `Calendar`'s have different `millis`, then they're different as per the second method.

In any case, the millis in your example should not both represent `2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z` so there's another problem in your code. Try this:

```
Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp( 1401561000000L );
Timestamp ts2 = new Timestamp( 1401595200000L );
System.err.println( ts1 );
System.err.println( ts2 );
```

Outputs:

```
2014-05-31 20:30:00.0
2014-06-01 06:00:00.0
```

Cheers,

Comment: I have fetched one value from UI and stored in Date object and other value is fetched from DB as Date object and both date objects are converted to calendar object .

Comment: And how did you arrive at the output `2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z`?

Comment: That looks like a `Date.toString`?

Comment: @staticx No that would end with timezone and year (`dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`). I'm guessing `Timestamp.toString()` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just compare the minutes and ignore the milliseconds or seconds do this:

You need to use

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

and possibly as well

```
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

if you just need the minutes to match.

---

Quick explanation of what is going on:

The [JavaDoc for Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) states:

> Compares the time values (millisecond offsets from the Epoch)
>   represented by two Calendar objects.

So you acknowledge that ".. long time in millis for both dates are different .."

[@JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) says in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505637/2591612):

> Calendar.setTime takes a java.util.Date, which is just a wrapper
>   around a long indicating the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan
>   1st 1970, UTC. It's not "in the format MM/dd/yyy" - that's a string
>   representation, not a java.util.Date. If it happens to print something
>   out in the format MM/dd/yyyy, that's just what Date.toString is doing
>   for you - it's not inherently part of the format.

This should answer your question about what is going on.

Note: java.util.Date has the same problem.

PS. A lot of people say use Joda Time, which I have heard is going to be in Java 8, but I have not personally tried it. If you are going to be using a lot of date code, I'd recommend you use it.

Comment: Overly underrated answer! I was facing the same issue in unit tests and after setting millisecond to 0, dates came to be equal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The milliseconds number is the "offical" time in Java. However, for a variety or reasons, there are numbers with the same date/time which have different numbers of milliseconds. Then normal reason is clock adjustments. E.g. Sometimes you have to add a second or two to account for irregularities in the earth's orbit. The other big source is when regions were first brought into the UTC, then some time zones moved hours.

THere is also the common source for these things: DST.
This will happen twice a year when you move to daylight saving time, on the one hand there are date/times which do not exists, as they were "skipped", and there are other times which happened twice, as the clock gets reset at midnight, so 11pm-midnight happens twice on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

I invoked compareTo on Date instead of Calendar and  got the correct result. It might be because of the fact that Calendar stores Timezone information but Date object does not.

Thanks